# EGZ theory Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem (elementary number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how can I Prove that a sequence of 29 numbers always contains 20 numbers summing up to a multiple of  10

I think that I must use EGZ theory twice but I can't prove it.

Comment: Welcome. Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: I think that I must use EGZ theory twice but I can't prove it, any help please

Comment: I assume EGZ is the Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem.

Comment: what if $a_n = 1$ for $n = 1 \ldots 29$ ? what if $a_{29} = 2$ ? etc.

Comment: I mean a set with 29 integer numbers contains subset with 20 numbers summing up to a multiple os 10

Comment: @user1952009, then take 20 ones?

Comment: yes,  I need to prove that a set with 29 integers has a subset of size 20 the sum of whose elements is a multiple of 10, using EGZ theory

Answer (score 2):

Seems like overkill, but here's how to do it using EGZ:

We work mod($10$).  The theorem tells us that any group of at least $19$ elements mod($10$) contains a sublist of ten elements that add to $0$. So..take our set of $29$ and extract ten that add to $0$ mod($10$).  Now remove those from the set.  We're left with $19$ elements.  We can, again, invoke the theorem to select ten new elements that add to $0$ mod($10$).  Combining these with the first ten gives us what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Summing to a multiple of 10 is the same as summing to 0 mod 10.

EGZ tells you that out of 19 numbers there will be a subset of size 10 that sums to 0 mod 10.

So if we have 29 numbers we take 10 away getting a subsequence that sums to 0 (mod 10), and are left with 19 numbers from which we can take another 10 away to get another sequence summing to 0 (mod 10).

Together that gives you 20.

Comment: thank you, and how can I prove a set with n numbers contains subset that the sum of whose elements is a multiple of n,